# Can anyone help me identify the problem with my Areca Palm

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, plant-health, diseases

I got this plant some 2 months ago from a local nursery and recently I noticed dark brown and yellow spots and now It started dying as you can see int the second image. I am watering it when the upper side of soils feels dry.
[[image: Dark brown spots][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sxcsq.jpg)
[[image: One stem has died][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/df1T5.jpg)
[image: Full picture]